# Use of Memory-mapped in Julia

Tags: out-of-memory, julia, memory-mapping

I have a Julia code, version 1.2, which performs a lot of operations on a `10000 x 10000 Array` . Due to `OutOfMemory()` error when I run the code, I’m exploring other options to run it, such as Memory-mapping. Concerning the use of `Mmap.mmap`, I’m a bit confused with the use of the Array that I map to my disk, due to little explanations on https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Mmap/index.html. Here is the beginning of my code:

```
using Distances
using LinearAlgebra
using Distributions
using Mmap
data=Float32.(rand(10000,15))
Eucldist=pairwise(Euclidean(),data,dims=1)
D=maximum(Eucldist.^2)
sigma2hat=mean(((Eucldist.^2)./D)[tril!(trues(size((Eucldist.^2)./D)),-1)])
L=exp.(-(Eucldist.^2/D)/(2*sigma2hat))
```

`L` is the `10000 x 10000 Array` with which I want to work, so I mapped it to my disk with

```
s = open("mmap.bin", "w+")
write(s, size(L,1))
write(s, size(L,2))
write(s, L)
close(s)
```

What am I supposed to do after that? The next step is to perform `K=eigen(L)` and apply other commands to `K`. How should I do that? With `K=eigen(L)` or `K=eigen(s)`? What’s the role of the object `s` and when does it get involved? Moreover, I don’t understand why I have to use `Mmap.sync!` and when. After each subsequent lines after `eigen(L)`? At the end of the code? How can I be sure that I’m using my disk space instead of RAM memory?Would like some highlights about memory-mapping, please. Thank you!

Comment: Any time you double-post, *please* cross link to your other(s): https://discourse.julialang.org/t/use-of-memory-mapped-i-o/28311. That's the courteous way to show respect for other peoples' time.

Comment: Just to be sure that I can show my problem to a maximum of people and gather a lot of suggestions because all users of stack Overflow and Julia forums are not necessarily the same

Comment: Right, but often people will say essentially the same thing. If they can read what someone already wrote, they can focus on just the novel part of their advice. Saves them some time, and you lose nothing by doing it.

Comment: Ok :-) Will take that into account next time ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If memory usage is a concern, it is often best to re-assign your very large arrays to 0, or to a similar type-safe small matrix, so that the memory can be garbage collected, assuming you are done with those intermediate matrices. After that, you just call Mmap.mmap() on your stored data file, with the type and dimensions of the data as second and third arguments to mmap, and then assign the function's return value to your variable, in this case L, resulting in L being bound to the file contents:

```
using Distances
using LinearAlgebra
using Distributions
using Mmap

function testmmap()
    data = Float32.(rand(10000, 15))
    Eucldist = pairwise(Euclidean(), data, dims=1)
    D = maximum(Eucldist.^2)
    sigma2hat = mean(((Eucldist.^2) ./ D)[tril!(trues(size((Eucldist.^2) ./ D)), -1)])
    L = exp.(-(Eucldist.^2 / D) / (2 * sigma2hat))
    s = open("./tmp/mmap.bin", "w+")
    write(s, size(L,1))
    write(s, size(L,2))
    write(s, L)
    close(s)

    # deref and gc collect
    Eucldist = data = L = zeros(Float32, 2, 2)
    GC.gc()

    s = open("./tmp/mmap.bin", "r+") # allow read and write
    m = read(s, Int)
    n = read(s, Int)
    L = Mmap.mmap(s, Matrix{Float32}, (m, n))  # now L references the file contents
    K = eigen(L)
    K
end

testmmap()
@time testmmap()  # 109.657995 seconds (17.48 k allocations: 4.673 GiB, 0.73% gc time)
```

Comment: Ok thank you :-) I know it’s slower but I have memory errors when I run the whole code without  memory mapping so I have no choice ;-) that’s just the beginning of my code

Comment: I like the suggestion of re-assigning large arrays to 0! Most of the time, I don't need intermediate matrices anymore!